# How to combine generating multiple variables in one class

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, class

I have a dataset as below

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
df= pd.DataFrame({'color': ['red', 'red,blue','red,blue,yellow', 'red,yellow', 'blue,yellow']})
```

I get a new variable like this

```
df['red'] = 0
df.ix[df['color'].str.contains("red") == True, 'red'  ] =1
```

similarly I can get `df['blue'] & df['yellow']`
Then i had to use it in `class` (i want to apply `pipeline`)

```
class Red():

def transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
    X['red'] = 0
    X.loc[X['color'].str.contains("red") == True, 'red'  ] = 1
    return X['red'].values.reshape(len(X),1)

def fit_transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
    self.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    return self.transform(X)

def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
    return self
```

It works but I want to get `class` which generates also `'blue' & 'yellow'`. Make classes for every 'color'? In the real dataset there are a few dozens 'colors'.
I'm new in class, please give any idea how to combine in one `class` generating multiple variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was surprised but it works

```
class Red(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

def transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
    X['red'] = 0
    X.loc[X['color'].str.contains("red") == True, 'red'  ] = 1
    X['blue'] = 0
    X.loc[X['color'].str.contains("blue") == True, 'blue'  ] = 1
    return X[['red', 'blue']].values.reshape(len(X),2)

def fit_transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
    self.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    return self.transform(X)

def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
    return self
```